# How to have a subitem inside another item in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am designing a WPF grid where I have to design datagrid rows such that each row is a parent and it will have some sub rows.Parent row and Child row shares same columns but different row. Also one column is Checkbox and it should enable only for child rows. Anyone suggest me how to design this in WPF xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox/> // Your Element
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Header2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid /> // Your Element
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        .   // As Many Colunm As You Like
        .
        .
        .

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```